# Change URL of custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently, I have URL like

> **/recipes-detail/?recipe=(Slug of recipe)**

How Can I change this to

> **/recipes-detail/(Slug of recipe)**

Currently, I am fetching the recipe custom plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Change Permalink Settings to Post name

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But recipe is not a post, Recipes are stored in Custom Table which I have created during plugin activation. So recipe doesn't have any post properties

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the .htaccess file a rewrite mode

```
RewriteRule ^recipes-detail/[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$/  ./recipes-detail/?recipe=$1
```

Now if you use this address yourwebsite.com/recipes-detail/cake-of-chocolate will work exactly as you will be doing  yourwebsite.com/recipes-detail/?recipe=cake-of-chocolate

So you can now build your urls with the friendly option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't change my URL, still showing the original URL. I even tried this by restarting the server but still no solution.

Comment: I updated the answer with more details that can help you

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I also tried the same format by using         function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^recipes-detail/[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$/', './recipes-detail/?recipe=$1', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');